# how to multiply a 2D array by a number in c

Tags: c, arrays

This code is meant to take a six digit number and see if the last digit is equal to the first digit + (the second digit * 3) + the third digit + (the forth digit * 3) + the fifth digit. It then mods that answer by 10 to give you the last number and whether the original six digit number is valid or not and if it is not what the actual last digit is. This code does not work at the multiplication bit as when you put in the number 365121 which is a correct number you get the first array slot equal to the whole number goes into the first array slot and the other numbers seem to be randomly generated. This is probably a simple mistake on my part.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int barcode_array[1][6], x = 0, y = 0, weighted_1 = 0, weighted_2 = 0, weighted_3 = 0, weighted_4 = 0, weighted_5 = 0, temp = 0, check_digit = 0, menu = 0, menu_2 = 0;
    while(x != 1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Do you want to input a barcode? \n1.Yes \n2.No \n: ");
        scanf("%d",&menu);
        y = 0;
        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                while (y != 1)
                {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Please input a barcode 6 numbers long: ");
                    scanf("%d",&barcode_array[0]);
                    weighted_1 = barcode_array[0][0];
                    weighted_2 = barcode_array[0][1] * 3;
                    weighted_3 = barcode_array[0][2];
                    weighted_4 = barcode_array[0][3] * 3;
                    weighted_5 = barcode_array[0][4];
                    temp = weighted_1 + weighted_2 + weighted_3 + weighted_4 + weighted_5;
                    printf("%d , %d , %d , %d , %d , %d , %d \n",temp, barcode_array[y][0], barcode_array[y][1], barcode_array[y][2], barcode_array[y][3], barcode_array[y][4]);
                    check_digit = temp % 10;
                    if (barcode_array[y][5] == check_digit)
                    {
                        printf("This is a valid barcode \n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("The barcode was not valid it should have ended in a %d \n",check_digit);
                    }
                    y = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `barcode_array[y][...]` is very wrong - it can only ever be `barcode_array[0][...]`.

Comment: You are using a 2-dimensional array, `int barcode_array[1][6]` but I do not think you need one! You are just storing a single sequence of 6 digits, you only need a single dimensional array. `int barcode_array[6]`. Then access the elements as :
`weighted_1 = barcode_array[0];
                    weighted_2 = barcode_array[1] * 3;
                    weighted_3 = barcode_array[2];
                    weighted_4 = barcode_array[3] * 3;
                    weighted_5 = barcode_array[4];`

Comment: moreover you seems to consider that the array will contains the digits. But a number (you read an `int` with `%d`) is just a number, not an array. You have either to extract digits from value (decomposition in base 10) or read the value as a string and deal with each digit (but so they are characters, not numbers, so you have to convert character 0 into value 0 and so on). By the way what is this silly `fflush(stdin)`?!

Comment: Write a simple program that calls `scanf` and then calls `printf` to show what you entered. You need to understand how `scanf` works before you can proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you do not parsing the 6-digit input with scanf function. Your scanf use is wrong.

Here is my solution;

First, I take the six digit number with scanf and store it in a simple int
Second, I parse the six digit number and store each digit in the array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int barcode_input;
    int barcode_array[6], x = 0, y = 0, temp = 0, check_digit = 0, menu = 0;

    while(x != 1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Do you want to input a barcode? \n1.Yes \n2.No \n: ");
        scanf("%d",&menu);
        y = 0;
        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                while (y != 1)
                {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Please input a barcode 6 numbers long: ");
                    scanf("%d",&barcode_input);
                    /* parse barcode_input and put each digit into array */
                    if( (barcode_input<=999999) && (barcode_input>99999) ) /* input must be a 6-digit number */
                    {
                        barcode_array[5] = barcode_input%10;
                        barcode_array[4] = ( (barcode_input - barcode_array[5]) / 10 ) %10;
                        barcode_array[3] = ( (barcode_input - barcode_array[5] - barcode_array[4]*10) /100) %10;
                        barcode_array[2] = ( (barcode_input - barcode_array[5] - barcode_array[4]*10 - barcode_array[3]*100) /1000) %10;
                        barcode_array[1] = ( (barcode_input - barcode_array[5] - barcode_array[4]*10 - barcode_array[3]*100 - barcode_array[2]*1000) / 10000) %10;
                        barcode_array[0] = ( (barcode_input - barcode_array[5] - barcode_array[4]*10 - barcode_array[3]*100 - barcode_array[2]*1000 - barcode_array[1]*10000) / 100000) %10;    
                        temp = barcode_array[0] + barcode_array[1]*3 + barcode_array[2] + barcode_array[3]*3 + barcode_array[4];
                        printf("%d , %d , %d , %d , %d , %d\n",barcode_array[0], barcode_array[1], barcode_array[2], barcode_array[3], barcode_array[4], barcode_array[5]);
                        check_digit = temp % 10;
                        if ( barcode_array[5] == check_digit )
                        {
                            printf("This is a valid barcode \n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("The barcode was not valid it should have ended in a %d \n",check_digit);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("The input MUST be 6-digit");
                    }

                    y = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output, I've just compiled it with **gcc**;

```
D:\SOF>gcc barcodecheck.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -o barcodecheck

D:\SOF>barcodecheck
Do you want to input a barcode?
1.Yes
2.No
: 1
Please input a barcode 6 numbers long: 1234567
The input MUST be 6-digitDo you want to input a barcode?
1.Yes
2.No
: 1
Please input a barcode 6 numbers long: 365121
3 , 6 , 5 , 1 , 2 , 1
This is a valid barcode
Do you want to input a barcode?
1.Yes
2.No
: 2
```

Hope that it helps!